# Filter R dataframe rows by matching value in consecutive columns

Tags: r, subset

I have a large dataframe of true (1) and false (0) information. Below is a reduced sample of it.

```
df <- read.table(text = "  0m-10m 0m-15m 0m-20m 0m-25m
                 X 1 0 1 1 
                 Y 1 1 0 0 
                 Z 0 1 0 1 ", header = T)
```

I need to subset rows where two consecutive contrasts are true (both == 1) so that the result looks like this

```
   0m-10m 0m-15m 0m-20m 0m-25m
X  1 0 1 1
Y  1 1 0 0
```

I can filter by rowSums >=2, but this is also true for row Z, which I need to exclude. Thoughts?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just remove the first and last columns, create a logical matrix with `&` and then use `rowSums` to create logical vector to subset

```
df[rowSums(df[-1] & df[-ncol(df)]) > 0,]
```

-output

```
  0m-10m 0m-15m 0m-20m 0m-25m
X      1      0      1      1
Y      1      1      0      0
```

The `rowSums` above is not based on a single data.  We are creating a logical matrix from two equal sized datasets by removing the first and last columns and then using `&` so, that if both have 1 in the same location, only it will return `TRUE` and FALSE otherwise.  `rowSums` on this matrix returns the sum of TRUE (or TRUE/FALSE -> 1/0)

```
> df[-1] & df[-ncol(df)]
  0m-15m 0m-20m 0m-25m
X  FALSE  FALSE   TRUE
Y   TRUE  FALSE  FALSE
Z  FALSE  FALSE  FALSE
> rowSums(df[-1] & df[-ncol(df)])
X Y Z 
1 1 0 
> rowSums(df[-1] & df[-ncol(df)]) > 0
    X     Y     Z 
 TRUE  TRUE FALSE
```

---

Or if we are looking for a general case, we may use `rle` - run-length-encoding on each row by looping over the rows with `apply` and `MARGIN = 1`.  The `rle` returns a `list` of `values` and `lengths` for each adjacent similar values.  Then, we create a logical vector based on the `lengths` and `values` i.e. if the 'values' is 1 and 'lengths' is 2.

```
n <- 2
df[apply(df, 1, FUN = function(x) with(rle(x), any(lengths == n & values))),]
  0m-10m 0m-15m 0m-20m 0m-25m
X      1      0      1      1
Y      1      1      0      0
```

-code breakup

```
> apply(df, 1, FUN = rle)
$X
Run Length Encoding
  lengths: Named int [1:3] 1 1 2
 - attr(*, "names")= chr [1:3] "0m-15m" "0m-20m" ""
  values : Named int [1:3] 1 0 1
 - attr(*, "names")= chr [1:3] "0m-10m" "0m-15m" "0m-25m"

$Y
Run Length Encoding
  lengths: Named int [1:2] 2 2
 - attr(*, "names")= chr [1:2] "0m-20m" ""
  values : Named int [1:2] 1 0
 - attr(*, "names")= chr [1:2] "0m-15m" "0m-25m"

$Z
Run Length Encoding
  lengths: Named int [1:4] 1 1 1 1
 - attr(*, "names")= chr [1:4] "0m-15m" "0m-20m" "0m-25m" ""
  values : Named int [1:4] 0 1 0 1
 - attr(*, "names")= chr [1:4] "0m-10m" "0m-15m" "0m-20m" "0m-25m"
> apply(df, 1, FUN = function(x) with(rle(x),lengths == n & values))
$X
0m-15m 0m-20m        
 FALSE  FALSE   TRUE 

$Y
0m-20m        
  TRUE  FALSE 

$Z
0m-15m 0m-20m 0m-25m        
 FALSE  FALSE  FALSE  FALSE 
> apply(df, 1, FUN = function(x) with(rle(x), any(lengths == n & values)))
    X     Y     Z 
 TRUE  TRUE FALSE
```

Comment: I should perhaps clarify that this is a small example of a dataframe with 12,939 rows and 8 columns. I don't think the first solution will suffice because rowSums just isn't cutting it. What does "values" refer to in your second solution?

Comment: @KalaDowney It doesn't matter whether you have 10 rows or 12000 rows.  The first solution is not based on rows.  It is checking every 2 alternate columns for 1

Comment: Ah! Sorry, that wasn't clear to me.

Comment: @KalaDowney i added the steps for better understanding. Hope it helps

Comment: @KalaDowney Based on your input, I assume there are no missing (`NA`) values

Comment: That is all very helpful, thank you! There's aren't any NA's, we omitted those early on.

Answer (score 1):

Here is an alternative way using pivot:

```
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)

df %>% 
  rownames_to_column("xyz") %>% 
  pivot_longer(
    -xyz
  ) %>% 
  group_by(xyz) %>% 
  mutate(helper = lag(value),
         flag = ifelse(value==1 & helper==1, 1,0)) %>% 
  filter(any(flag==1)) %>% 
  pivot_wider(
    names_from = name,
    values_from = value,
    values_fill = 0
  ) %>% 
  summarize(across(starts_with("X"), sum)) %>% 
  column_to_rownames("xyz")
```

```
  X0m.10m X0m.15m X0m.20m X0m.25m
X       1       0       1       1
Y       1       1       0       0
```

Answer (score 0):

A solution based on the creation of an auxiliary column concatenating all original columns as a string (using `tidyr::unite`) and then using `stringr::str_detect` on the strings:

```r
library(tidyverse)

df <- read.table(text = "  0m-10m 0m-15m 0m-20m 0m-25m
                 X 1 0 1 1 
                 Y 1 1 0 0 
                 Z 0 1 0 1 ", header = T)

df %>% 
  unite(aux, sep = "", remove = F) %>% 
  filter(str_detect(aux, "11")) %>%
  select(-aux)

#>   X0m.10m X0m.15m X0m.20m X0m.25m
#> X       1       0       1       1
#> Y       1       1       0       0
```